# Is there a quick way to split a (very) long equation?

Tags: formatting, input

I'm generating LaTeX code from Mathematica, which I must insert into my input .tex file. The problem is that equations are too long to fit on the page, and it takes a long time to split them up. Is there any way to split such long equations quickly?

Here is the input:

```
\left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5
\right)
+g_2 \left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5
\right){}^{\wedge}2
+g_3 \left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5
\right){}^{\wedge}3
+ g_4 \left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}4
+g_5 \left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}5
+g_6 \left( 
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}6
+g_7 \left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}7
+g_8 \left(
  \epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+
  \epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5
\right){}^{\wedge}8
```

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: It probably depends on what editor you are using to create the LaTeX file.  Most modern editors don't care how long the line is, so perhaps you don't need to break it?

Comment: From a previous post I see you are using WinEdit, so maybe this link will help? http://yangfeng.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/winedt-auto-wrap/

Comment: You can if you remove the `\left` and `\right`, which make the formula in between unsplittable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All those `\left` and `\right` make the formula unsplittable. If your formulas all have that format, you can do in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{mathematica}
 {\begin{quote}%
  % neutralize \left and \right
  \def\left{}\def\right{}%
  % add some space around operation signs
  \medmuskip=4mu plus 2mu minus 2mu
  % correct the horrible ^{\wedge}<exponent>
  \def\wedge{\aftergroup{\aftergroup}\aftergroup^}%
  $}
 {$\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\begin{mathematica}
\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon 
^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5\right)+g_2\left(\epsilon 
^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon ^5 \phi 
_5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}2 
+g_3\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi 
_4+\epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 \phi 
_5\right){}^{\wedge}3 + g_4\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi _3 
+\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 
\phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}4+g_5\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi 
_3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 
\phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}5+g_6\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi 
_3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 
\phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}6+g_7\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi 
_3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 
\phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}7+g_8\left(\epsilon ^1 \phi _1+ \epsilon ^2 \phi _2 + \epsilon ^3 \phi 
_3 +\epsilon ^4 \phi _4+\epsilon ^5 \phi _5+\epsilon ^6 \phi _5+\epsilon ^7 \phi _5+\epsilon ^8 
\phi _5\right){}^{\wedge}8
\end{mathematica}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cant read the language. cant I avoid the language and put the only mathematics?

Comment: I have inserted your style in my latex file but didn't run :-(

Comment: @Forhad: The language is so called blind text, which shows your equation embeded in some filling text. You mention that the code "didn't run" when you try it. What's the error?

Comment: I love the beautiful trick that converts the awful `\wedge` into a "normal" exponentiation operator!

Answer (score 8):

This is only peripheral to your question but, please, don't inflict that on your readers; I almost fell asleep halfway through parsing that mathematical expression of yours. Why not write it in a more compact form, using sums?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[  
    \left(
        \sum_{j=1}^4 \epsilon^j \phi_j +
        \left(
            \sum_{k=5}^8 \epsilon^k 
        \right) \phi_5
    \right)
    + \sum_{i=2}^8 g_i
    \left(
        \sum_{j=1}^4 \epsilon^j \phi_j +
        \left(
            \sum_{k=5}^8 \epsilon^k 
        \right) \phi_5
    \right)^i
\]

\vspace{3em}
\noindent
Alternatively:
\[
    x + \sum_{i=2}^8 g_i x^i \,,
\]
where
\[
    x \triangleq
    \sum_{j=1}^4 \epsilon^j \phi_j +
    \left(
        \sum_{k=5}^8 \epsilon^k 
    \right) \phi_5 \,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: is your formula missing something?

Comment: @karlkoeller Is it? Perhaps. You tell me...

Comment: ...an exponent?

Comment: @karlkoeller You're right. Oops! I'll correct that.

Comment: @karlkoeller Fixed (hopefully).

Comment: Your conversation has made me laugh. :-D

Comment: Possibly one could also do something with the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_summation_convention) here?

Comment: Defining `g_1=1`, the summary equation after "Alternatively" could be simplified further to a single sum over 8 items of the form `g_i x^i`. :-)

Comment: @Mico, this would be certainly better, but we don't know whether `g_1` is used somewhere else in Forhad's code, so... And anyway I think she/he has got the message and surely knows how to adjust it to her/his needs. Finally, this conversation is risking to be migrated to math.SX :-D